# Use email to update Facebook page I manage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I would like to update a Facebook page I manage using email.  I am the administrator.  Can I do this without posting directly on my personal page?

I will be working remotely and won't have internet access but will have limited email access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do that.

From [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/165112120218408#How-do-I-use-email-to-update-people-who-like-my-Page?)

> #### How do I use email to update people who like my Page?
>
> You can post to your Page by sending an email to a special admin-facing email address assigned to your Page. Put your message in the subject line of the email and leave the body blank. To upload a photo or video, attach it to an email and send it to this address with the caption in the subject line. To find your Page's email address:
>
> 1. At the top of your Page, click **Edit Page**
> 2. Select **Edit Settings**
> 3. Click **More...** and select **Mobile** from the dropdown menu
> 4. Find your Page's email address under **With Mobile Email**

Comment: I have tried this but because my page is linked to my personal acct, when I post it posts as me, not my page.  Perhaps I have to decouple my page from my personal account....

Comment: THANKS.  I was hoping there was a way I could choose the page.

Comment: I just did a test and my post was listed as being by the page. Make sure that "You are posting, commenting, and liking as..." at the top of the page is set to the name of the page, not your user account.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/pages/WISSARD-Whillans-Ice-Stream-Subglacial-Access-Research-Drilling-Project/322629720135

Comment: okay.  When I am posting (in Antarctica) I can't see the web (So I can't flip back and forth as a user) Perhaps I can just leave myself logged in as the page when I leave for the field, and I can update only as the page...

Comment: As far as I know, that setting stays until you explicitly flip it, so, yeah.

Comment: okay stay tuned from Antarctica! thanks